# Playframework - activator UI - connection refused when accessing from internet

Tags: playframework, port, digital-ocean

I have installed the playframework in digital ocean (Ubuntu) and installed activator UI. the UI is located at http:// 127.0.0.1:8888, however I cannot access this port from the internet. i.e. say my digitalocean server IP is 10.100.10.10, i cannot access http:// 10.100.10.10:8888
from my personal PC

however I can wget using localhost in the server, any idea how can I access this page from the internet?

```
wget http:// 127.0.0.1:8888
--2014-04-16 16:01:38--  http:// 127.0.0.1:8888/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8888... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 303 See Other
Location: /home [following]
--2014-04-16 16:01:38--  http:// 127.0.0.1:8888/home
Reusing existing connection to 127.0.0.1:8888.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK

sudo netstat -ntulp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      429/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      429/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8888          :::*                    LISTEN      17498/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::28667                :::*                    LISTEN      17498/java
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, it is due to the service forced to listen 127.0.0.1, setting below can resolve and launch Activator on a WAN on port 80

./activator -Dhttp.address=0.0.0.0 -Dhttp.port=80